# Running an Angular2 app on EC2

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'd like to run a basic Angular 2 app on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. 
In my case, I installed Angular CLI, and created a new site in /var/www

```
ng new test
```

then

```
ng serve --port 8080
```

It *looks* like my basic Angular2 app is running fine

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:8080, open your browser on http://localhost:8080 **
Hash: e0094cf33de0e6b8f264
Time: 9090ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 171 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 5.28 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.5 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

I know port 8080 is open in my security groups, because I *just* ran a basic Node JS app a few minutes ago in /var/www. When I try to go to http://[Public DNS]:8080, Safari says it can't connect. There's also nothing in my apache logs.

Comment: I'd recommend `ng build`ing the site and deploying the resulting files statically - `ng serve` is a development server, it's not meant for production use.

Comment: To build on what @jonrsharpe said, [relevant issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274) about not recommending `ng serve` for production use. Also [deployment documentation for Angular](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: I'm sorta wondering why my sample CLI app didn't work, when it looks like I was following the instructions here closely (at least as far as getting Angular to work).https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1

Comment: I mean, I get I should be using something more robust than the vanilla server. But it seems like the dev server should be working.

Comment: did you try ng serve --host 0.0.0.0  --port 8080 ?

Comment: I just did ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 and when I go to the URL it says Invalid Host header

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the *real* issue is this:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6070

I've tried editing the server.js file and running with the --publicHost option, but those aren't working. I'm using non CLI Angular with the default port 3000 and that's working on EC2 (after adding the security group settings).